# Problems on finding the shortest path using Dijkstra

Tags: c++, shortest-path, dijkstra

I'm implementing Dijjkstra's algorithm to find the shortest path on a network. Starting from an origin node s, I need to calculate the shortest path to reach all the existed nodes on the network. But the algorithm is not doing it correctly.

Here's the code (HEU is a struct of a Graph):

```
int dijkstra(GRAPHD &HEU, int s) {
HEU.d[s] = 0; 
for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
    if (i != s)
        HEU.d[i] = INT_MAX; 
}
for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
    HEU.S[i] = 0; 
    HEU.Q[i] = i; 
}

while (!vazio(HEU)) {
    int u = extract_mimimum(HEU);
    HEU.S[u] = 1;
    retira(HEU, u);
    for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
        if (HEU.qr[u][i] != -1) { //it's just to indicate that the position is not empty
            if (HEU.qr[u][i] != -2) { //it's just to indicate that the position is not empty
                if (HEU.d[HEU.qr[u][i]] > HEU.d[u] + HEU.c[u][HEU.qr[u][i]])
                    HEU.d[HEU.qr[u][i]] = HEU.d[u] + HEU.c[u][HEU.qr[u][i]];
            }
        }
    }
}


return HEU.d;
}
```

The problem is when starting from node 2.
All the distances on the matrix HEU.c[ ][ ] are 1 and the graph is as follows:

```
HEU.qr[1][1] = 5;

HEU.qr[2][1] = 1;

HEU.qr[2][2] = 3;

HEU.qr[3][1] = 7;

HEU.qr[3][2] = 4;

HEU.qr[4][1] = 8;

HEU.qr[5][1] = 9;

HEU.qr[6][1] = 2;

HEU.qr[6][2] = 5;

HEU.qr[7][1] = 11;

HEU.qr[7][2] = 6;

HEU.qr[8][1] = 7;

HEU.qr[9][1] = 10;

HEU.qr[10][1] = 6;

HEU.qr[10][2] = 11;

HEU.qr[11][1] = 15;

HEU.qr[12][1] = 8;

HEU.qr[13][1] = 9;

HEU.qr[14][1] = 10;

HEU.qr[14][2] = 13;

HEU.qr[15][1] = 14;

HEU.qr[15][2] = 16;

HEU.qr[16][1] = 12;
```

For example, HEU.qr[16][1] = 12 means that node 16 has only one neighbor and its node 12. Then, HEU.qr[15][1] = 14 and HEU.qr[15][2] = 16 node 15 has two neighbors that are 14 and 16.

The auxiliar functions are as follows:

```
int vazio(GRAPHD &HEU) {
for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
    if (HEU.Q[i] != 0)
        return 0;
}
return 1;
}

int extract_mimimum(GRAPHD &HEU) {
int min = INT_MAX;
for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
    if (HEU.Q[i] != 0) {
        if (HEU.d[i] < min) {
            min = i;                
        }
    }
}
return min;
}

void retira(GRAPHD &HEU, int a) {
for (int i = 1; i <= HEU.nb_nodes; i++) {
    if (HEU.Q[i] == a) HEU.Q[i] = 0;
}
 }
```

The distance vector starting from node 2 should be 1 0 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 3 6 6 5 4 5 but the algorithm finds 1 0 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 4 3 8 8 7 6 7. 
Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Use caution when tagging languages. This is clearly not C code and you don't want to bring a ravening horde of angry C programmers down upon your head.

Comment: Your question will receive more love if you adapt the code into a [mcve] or something close to it. Often we need to see the code in context or compile and run it to assist yo properly.